# Can't publish posts, Jetpack won't connect, empty notification emails to my inbox

Tags: publish, notifications, plugin-jetpack

I own a self-hosted Wordpress blog and I am experiencing a lot of issues:

- Jetpack stopped working and it won't connect: `verify_secrets_missing : The Jetpack server encountered the following client error: Verification took too long`;
- can't post any entry, the *Publish* button has been replaced with *Send for revision*;
- emails are sent to my inbox to notify a new comment, except there's no actual new comment and the email has empty fields;
- everytime I try to add a new user an empty email is sent to my inbox and the user isn't actually added.

I am desperate to bring my blog back to normal, so far I have:

- deactivated all plugins and then re-activated;
- switched to the Twenty Eleven theme to rule out any theme-specific problems;
- reset the plugins folder by FTP;
- re-uploaded all files & folders (except the wp-content folder) from a fresh download of WordPress.

Needless to say all this attempts have miserably failed. Then I've found out that my hosting had set the space for my DB to 5MB, now I have reset the space to 400MB, but still the issue remains. Any ideas about what can I try to get all back to normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB space run out, I had to wait for the hosting to *make space* and extend the DB size to the amount I requested.